# Simple image gallery JS

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I'm trying to create a simple image gallery with radio buttons. Images are set to Display: none; by default. What I want is for them to display as block when I click on their respective buttons.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .img { width: 250px;
                max-height: 300px;
                display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function picture (a) {
            var pic = document.getElementById('image')
            if (a == 1) {
                pic.src="julia1.jpg"
            } else { pic.src="julia2.jpg"}

            pic.style.display ="block";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="img" id="image" src="julia1.jpg">
    <form action="">
        <input type="radio" onclick="picture(1)" name="picture"></input>
        <input type="radio" onclick="picture(2)" name="picture"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On the browser console it says that object is not a function. What does that mean? (thats for both input tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line should read

```
pic.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: the function and the input elements shouldn't be named the same.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for simple js gallery check this example :

https://codepen.io/zarokr/pen/ZEzBYvY

```
let current = document.getElementById('current');
let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');

for(let i = 0; i<thumbnails.length; i++){
    thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click',changeImage);
}

function changeImage(){
    let getsrc = this.getAttribute('src');
    current.setAttribute('src',getsrc);
}
```